# Can we use normal mobile website html template for phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a phone application, which is completely a new thing to me.Can we use a mobile responsive html template for phonegap theme. As of now am planning to use following theme for my phonegap iphone application. The theme is mobile responsive.

http://flatfull.com/themes/scale/index.html

Can I use the same or is there any restriction for Phonegap theme. Please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that'll work fine. It supports standard HTML/CSS frontends and I've even seen people integrating their SQL database so it basically mirrors a traditional setup :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can totally use this as cordova(Phonegap) is also using HTML but make sure it's in HTML5 because cordova application supports HTML5 and same for CSS3. By using this there will be some design changes you have to fix according to device.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, HTML resources(HTML, CSS, javascript) in any form can be used to make mobile applications with Cordova. But if you need to use native features of device, then additional plugins need to be added.